# iOS table view show prototype cell after deleting all section and row

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have implemented  tableView to show records. The section is the month of several records, and row is the record. I used prototype cell. But when I am deleting the last row in last section of the tableview, it shows strange behavior. The tableview shows an empty section header and a prototype cell itself.

Comment: Show your code. Without code no one can judge actual your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure once all rows are deleted you are also setting number of sections to 0